# Identifying device based on the MAC address

Tags: network, mac-address

Suppose we know that MAC address A belongs to a certain device (say an iPhone 5), and MAC address B also belongs to an iPhone 5. If we have a MAC address C which is in between A and B, does this guarantee that C is an iPhone 5 or could it be any Apple product?

EDIT: Suppose they all have the same 3 byte prefix, e.g.:

```
A=44:2A:60:01:01:01
B=44:2A:60:21:AA:F4
C=44:2A:60:01:02:03
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be any product, not just any Apple product.

The first 3 bytes (24 bits) of the MAC address identify the vendor of the NIC (Network Interface Card). If Apple owns the blocks 00:00:01 and 00:00:03, then MAC-address 00:00:02:00:00:01 could belong to Cisco as well as any other vendor.

And besides, almost every NIC allows changing (spoofing) the MAC-address. They are not really that reliable, especially when people know you are trying to identify devices based on their MAC-address.

Edit: In reply to your edit, yes those would all be from the same NIC vendor, given that the user has not changed his MAC-address manually.

Comment: Vendor in this case should be NIC vendor, as Apple will buy their NICs.

Comment: @ManuelFaux You're right! Edited post accordingly.

Comment: @ManuelFaux In the most common cases you would be right. But I have seen a vendor deliver Ethernet chips without assigned MAC addresses, and you had to get your own.